# Sench Touch 2: panel won't scroll on mobile devices

Tags: html, extjs, mobile, sencha-touch-2

I have an app that is comprised of a tab bar layout with multiple pages, one of the pages is a list view and one is a "detail view" which is basically a panel.

The panel won't scroll on mobile devices. It works fine on Desktop (Chrome/Safari) but won't scroll on mobile devices.  I've tested it on Safari / Chrome on iOS, and Chrome on Android.

The demo of the app is here: simbro5-80.terminal.com
The source code is here: github.com/simbro/Geograph

Here are some snippets:

**Main View (extends Ext.tab.Panel) :**

```
{
    title: 'News',
    layout: 'fit',
    iconCls: 'news',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'itemsListView'
        }
    ]
},
{
    title: 'Item Details',
    layout: 'fit',
    hidden: true,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'itemDetailView'
        }
    ]
},
```

**Detail View:**

```
Ext.define('Geograph.view.ItemDetailView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'itemDetailView',

    config: {
        title: 'Details',
        //layout: 'fit',
        tpl: [
            '<img src="{thumb}" alt="" />',
            '<h2>{name}</h2>'
        ],
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical'
        },
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        data: null,
        items: [{
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Item Details',
            items: [{
                ui: 'back',
                text: 'Back',
                id: 'backBtn'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

P.S. I'm using Sencha Touch 2.4.1

Comment: Just a thought: I'm setting the data for the panel in the controller when a user clicks on a list item. Do I then need to refresh / redraw the panel?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to

```
scrollable: true
```

Just seeing if explicitly setting this makes any difference for you

Comment: Ok, just tried setting scrollable to true, but it hasn't fixed the issue. Still can't scroll on mobile devices :(

Comment: Hmm ok, I am seeing examples of using vbox layout on the parent item, so try changing from fit to vbox on your Item Details panel

Comment: Thanks Mindparse, I tried setting layout: 'vbox' on the main view, but it still didn't work :-(    stumped!

Comment: Ok I'm able to replicate this problem on Desktop now.  The issue is the build tool, when I run "sencha app build", the resulting build is broke, in as far as the the panel doesn't scroll any more. I think this should be asked as a new question.  Thanks for your help mindparse.